# How to prevent showing javascript alert message on page refresh in MVC5?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5

When i reload the page the javascript alert message also shows, i just want to show alert message when i click submit button.
here is the code

```
         @{
       if (ViewBag.message != null)
       {
         <script type="text/javascript">
         alert(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.message)));
     </script>
    }
 }
```

Comment: If you only want to show it when the submit button is clicked, why not attach it to the click or submit event instead of just always having it there? Shove whatever you needed access to from your server Raw call there into a html hidden field or javascript variable, if that's why.

Comment: @Talukder, Instead of using above code, you can use simple jQuery.



$("#ButtonId").click(function(){
alert(Json.Encode(ViewBag.message));
});